# Search bar matching with element from object created with innerHTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, innerhtml

I've been trying to match the value from my search with the elements from my array displayed on a list. I'm struggling since I displayed these elements using innerHTML and I can't find the way to match them up.

I've tried to get access to the parentElement but I couldn't, I'm not sure what I've been missing here.

```js
// SERIES DATA

let listSeries = 
[
{film: ['Breaking Bad', 'Better Call Saul', 'Game of Thrones', 'Ozark', 'Peaky Blinders', 'Stranger Things', 
        'Sex Eductaion', '13 Reasons Why', 'Skins', 'One of Us Is Lying'], genre: "Drama"},

{film: ['Servant', 'Penny Dreadful', 'Them', 'The Haunting of Bly Manor', 'Sweet Home', 'The Haunting of Hill House',
         'Haunted', 'Marianne', 'The Midnight Club'], genre: "Horror"},

{film: ['Rick and Morty', 'The Office US', 'The Office UK', 'Friends', 'Seinfeld', 'The Simpsons', 'The Good Place',
         'Two and a Half Men'], genre: "Comedy"}
]



// SEARCH SERIES

search.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let word = search.value;
      listSeries.forEach(e => {
        let foundIt = e.film.includes(word);
        e.toggle("hide", !foundIt);
      })
```

codeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/GasparBonari/lll/master?file=%2Flibraryscript.js

Comment: I made a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS in a [mcve] and fix the missing `)`

Comment: I added a codeSandBox where you can see the project, thanks. @mplungjan

Comment: `class Display {
  tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');

  add(libraryOfSeries) {` does not look like a proper JS class

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? I haven't had any problem with that class.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/p781ady5/

Comment: tableBody property is in the public field and then I have the add() method. Could you please re-write the class to see how it supposed to look like ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `tr`'s `id` attribute to the name of the series and then look it up via `document.getElementById(...)` in your event handler function, e.g.

```js
'use strict';

const btnAddSeries = document.querySelector(".btn-primary");
const btnSearch = document.querySelector(".btn-outline-success");
const seriesForm = document.querySelector("#seriesForm");
const search = document.querySelector("#searchTxt");
const listSeries = [
  {
    film: [
      'Breaking Bad', 
      'Better Call Saul', 
      'Game of Thrones', 
      'Ozark', 
      'Peaky Blinders', 
      'Stranger Things',
      'Sex Eductaion', 
      '13 Reasons Why', 
      'Skins', 
      'One of Us Is Lying'
    ],
    genre: "Drama"
  },
  {
    film: [
      'Servant', 
      'Penny Dreadful', 
      'Them', 
      'The Haunting of Bly Manor', 
      'Sweet Home', 
      'The Haunting of Hill House',
      'Haunted', 
      'True Blood', 
      'The Midnight Club'
    ],
    genre: "Horror"
  },
  {
    film: [
      'Rick and Morty', 
      'The Office US', 
      'The Office UK', 
      'Friends', 
      'Seinfeld', 
      'The Simpsons', 
      'The Good Place',
      'Two and a Half Men'
    ],
    genre: "Comedy"
  }
]

class Series {
  constructor(series, type) {
    this.series = series;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class Display {
  tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');

  add(libraryOfSeries) {
    const uiString = `<tr id="${libraryOfSeries.series}" class="series">
                      <td class="series-name">${libraryOfSeries.series}</td>
                      <td class="table-dark">${libraryOfSeries.type}</td>
                      <td><button class="btn1 btn-primary">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>`;
    tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;
  }
}

// DISPLAY SERIES
function displaySeries(series, genreToFilter) {
  const filterSeries = series.find(item => item.genre === genreToFilter);
  for (let i of filterSeries.film) {
    const currentSeries = new Series(i, filterSeries.genre);
    const display = new Display;
    display.add(currentSeries)
  }
}

// CALLING THE FUNCTION DISPLAY

function updateUI() {
  displaySeries(listSeries, "Drama");
  displaySeries(listSeries, "Comedy");
  displaySeries(listSeries, "Horror");
}

updateUI();

// SEARCH SERIES
search.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const word = search.value;
  listSeries.forEach(e => {
    e.film.forEach(name => {
      const match = name.toUpperCase().includes(word.toUpperCase());
      const tr = document.getElementById(name);
      tr.style.display = match ? '' : 'none';
    });    
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="searchTxt" type="text">
<table>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried your code but the display doesn't match with the word. The display changes while typing but I don't understand what it's trying to match. Could u check that please ? I'm really lost here. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome. It simply checks whether the input value is contained in the title in a case-sensitive manner: `name.includes(word)`. If you want a case-insensitive search you could instead do something like `name.toUpperCase().includes(word.toUpperCase())`. I have updated the code in the answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh! I was typing in lower case while the elements from my arrays start with upper case.  Thank you for showing me and being clear. I really appreciate your help!